# performance versus reusability

Tags: optimization, theory, code-reuse, vba

How can I write functions that are reusable without sacrificing performance? I am repeatedly coming up against the situation where I want to write a function in a way that makes it reusable (e.g. it makes no assumptions about the data environment) but knowing the overall flow of the program I know it isn't the most efficent method. For example if I want to write a function that validates a stock code but is reusable I can't just assume that the recordset is open. However if I open and close the recordset everytime the function is called then the performance hit when looping through thousands of rows could be huge.

So for performance I might have:

```
Function IsValidStockRef(strStockRef, rstStockRecords)
    rstStockRecords.Find ("stockref='" & strStockRef & "'")
    IsValidStockRef = Not rstStockRecords.EOF
End Function
```

But for reusability I would need something like the following:

```
Function IsValidStockRef(strStockRef)
    Dim rstStockRecords As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rstStockRecords = New ADODB.Recordset
    rstStockRecords.Open strTable, gconnADO

    rstStockRecords.Find ("stockref='" & strStockRef & "'")
    IsValidStockRef = Not rstStockRecords.EOF

    rstStockRecords.Close
    Set rstStockRecords = Nothing
End Function
```

I'm concerned that the impact on performance of opening and closing that recordset when called from within a loop over thousands of rows/records would be severe but using the first method makes the function less reusable.

What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding) and of [Clean readable code vs fast hard to read code. When to cross the line?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89620/clean-readable-code-vs-fast-hard-to-read-code-when-to-cross-the-line)

Answer (score 13):

You should do whatever yields the greater business value in this situation.

Writing software is always a trade-off. Almost never are all valid goals (maintainability, performance, clarity, conciseness, security etc. etc.) completely aligned. Do not fall into the trap of those short-sighted people who consider one of these dimensions as paramount and tell you to sacrifice *everything* to it.

Instead, understand what risks and what benefits each alternative offers, quantize them and go with the one that maximizes the outcome. (You don't have to actually make numerical estimates, of course. It's enough to weigh factors such as "using this class means locking us into that hash algorithm, but since we're not using it to guard against *malicious* attack, only for convenience, this one is good enough that we can just ignore the 1:1,000,000,000 chance of an *accidental* collision".)

The most important thing is to remember that they *are* trade-offs; no single principle justifies *everything* to satisfy, and no decision, once taken, need stand *eternally*. You may always have to revise in hindsight when circumstances change in a way you didn't foresee. That's a pain, but not nearly as painful as making the same decision *without* hindsight.

Comment: While what you say is true in general, something should be said for writing code to protect against any possible case vs having prerequisites.  In my humble opinion, there is nothing wrong with simply expecting that the recordset is already open when called, given enough documentation.  If anything, if this is a method in a library, perform a quick check if it is open, and if it isn't, throw an exception.  No need to "make it work" in any possible scenario.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of these seems more reusable than the other. They just seem to be at different **abstraction levels**. The first is for calling code that understands the stock system intimately enough to know that validating a stock reference means looking through a `Recordset` with some kind of query. The second is for calling code that just wants to know whether a stock code is valid or not and has no interest concerning itself with how you'd verify such a thing.

But [as with most abstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html), this one is "leaky". In this case the abstraction leaks through its performance- the calling code *can't* completely ignore how validation is implemented because if it did, it might call into that function thousands of times as you described and seriously degrade overall performance.

Ultimately, if you have to choose between poorly abstracted code and unacceptable performance, you have to choose the poorly abstracted code. But first, you should look for a better solution- a compromise that maintains acceptable performance and presents a decent (if not ideal) abstraction. Unfortunately I don't know VBA very well, but in an OO language, my first thought would be to give calling code a class with methods like:

```
BeginValidation()
IsValidStockRef(strStockRef)
EndValidation()
```

Here your `Begin...` and `End...` methods do the one-time lifecycle management of the record set, the `IsValidStockRef` matches your first version, but uses this record set which the class itself has taken responsibility for, rather than having it passed in. Calling code would then call the `Begin...` and `End...` methods outside of the loop, and the validation method inside.

**Note:** This is only a very rough illustrative example, and might be considered a first-pass at refactoring. The names could probably use tweaking, and depending on the language there should be a more clean or idiomatic way to do it (C# for example could use the constructor to begin and `Dispose()` to end). Ideally code that just wants to check if a stock ref is valid shouldn't itself have to do any lifecycle management at all.

This represents a slight degredation to the abstraction we're presenting: now calling code needs to know enough about validation to understand that it's something which requires some kind of setup and teardown. But in return for that relatively modest compromise, we now have methods that can be used easily by calling code, without hurting our performance.

Comment: Downvoter: Any particular reason, out of interest?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I'll take a guess. `BeginValidation`, `EndValidation`, and `IsValidStockRef` have a special relationship with each other. Knowledge of that relationship is more complex than the knowledge that would be required to directly handle a `RecordSet`. And the knowledge required to handle a `RecordSet` is more broadly applicable.

Comment: @Cory I agree to some extent, and my hand was forced a bit by lack of knowledge about vba. I did try to point this out with the next sentence, but maybe my wording wasn't clear or strong enough. I've made an edit to try to make this a little clearer

Comment: An interesting note, in C#, you'd be expected to use the `using` statement to do this job. In other languages (those which use exceptions anyway), to do the same work as `using`, you'd need to use `try {} finally {}` to guarantee proper disposal, and even then it's sometimes impossible to correctly wrap all code that might `throw`. This is a potential issue with all the solutions mentioned here, and I am also unsure how this should be resolved in VBA.

Comment: @Cory: And in C++, you would simply use RAII.

Answer (score 3):

For a long time, I used to implement a complicated system of checks to be able to use database transactions.  The transaction logic goes as follows:  open a transaction, perform the database operations, rollback upon error or commit on success.  The complication comes from what happens when you want an additional operation to be performed within the same transaction.  You'd either need to write a second method entirely which does both operations, or you could call your original method from a second, opening a transaction only if one hasn't already been opened and committing/rolling back changes only if you were the one to open the transaction.

For example:

```
public void method1() {
    boolean selfOpened = false;
    if(!transaction.isOpen()) {
        selfOpened = true;
        transaction.open();
    }

    try {
        performDbOperations();
        method2();

        if(selfOpened) 
            transaction.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if(selfOpened) 
            transaction.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}

public void method2() {
    boolean selfOpened = false;
    if(!transaction.isOpen()) { 
        selfOpened = true;
        transaction.open();
    }

    try {
        performMoreDbOperations();

        if(selfOpened) 
            transaction.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if(selfOpened) 
            transaction.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Please note, I'm not advocating the above code by any means.  This should serve as an example of what *not* to do!

It seemed silly to create a second method to perform the same logic as the first plus something extra, yet I wanted to be able to call the database API section of the program and seal off problems there.  However, while this partially solved my problem, every method I wrote involved adding this verbose logic of checking if a transaction is already open, and committing/rolling back changes if my method opened it.

The problem was conceptual.  I shouldn't have attempted to embrace every possible scenario.  The proper approach was to house transaction logic in a single method taking a second method as a parameter that would perform the actual database logic. That logic *assumes* the transaction is open and does not even perform a check.  These methods could be called in combination so that these methods weren't cluttered with unnecessary transaction logic.

The reason I mention this is because my mistake was to assume that I needed to make my method work in any situation.  In doing so, not only was my called method checking if a transaction was open, but also those that it called.  In this case, it is not a major performance hit, but if say, I needed to verify the existence of a record in the database before proceeding, I would be checking for every method which requires it when I should have just assumed all along that the caller should be made aware that the record should exist.  If the method is called anyway, this is undefined behavior and you need not worry about what happens.

Rather you should provide plenty of documentation, and write what you expect to be true before a call is made to your method.  If it is important enough, add it as a comment before your method so that there should be no mistake (javadoc provides nice support for this sort of thing in java).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could have two overloaded functions. That way you can use both of them according to the situation.

You can't never (I've never seen it happen) optimize for everything, so you got to settle for something. Choose what you believe is more important.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing a lot in VBA and overloading isn't an option. I could use an `Optional` parameter though to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 2):

2 functions: one opens the recordset and passes it to a data analysis function.

The first can be bypassed if you already have an open recordset. The second can assume that it will be passed an open recordset, ignoring where it came from, and process the data.

You have both performance and re-usability then!

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to open the recordset for the caller, but otherwise I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Optimisation (besides micro-optimization) is directly at odds with modularity.

Modularity works by isolating code from it's global context, whereas performance optimization exploits global context to minimise what the code has to do. Modularity is the benefit of low-coupling, whereas (the potential for) very high performance is the benefit of high-coupling.

The answer is architectural. Consider the pieces of the code that you are going to want to reuse. Perhaps it's the price calculation component, or configuration validation logic.

Then you should write the code that interacts with that component for reusability. Within a component where you can never use just part of the code you can optimise for performance since you know no one else will be use it.

The trick of it is determining what your components are.

**tl;dr:** between components write with modularity in mind, within components write with performance in mind.

Comment: Modularity and optimisation are _not necessarily_ at odds. Modern compilers can inline pretty much anything anywhere, so no matter how modular you write, as long as the compiler can stitch it together to a “non-modular executable”, there's no reason it couldn't be as fast as code that was written non-modular in the first place. Of course, not all compilers can do this very well, but...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Well I meant at the source code level, but you are very right. There is no reason a sufficiently smart compiler couldn't replace your bubble sort with a quick sort!